# Elliptic regularity for two dimensional domains

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

Suppose $ \Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $ R^2$.  I am interested in the regularity of solutions to 
$$-\Delta u(x) = f(x)  \mbox{ in } \Omega$$ with $ u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.

If $ f \in L^1(\Omega)$ then one just misses $ u \in C(\Omega)$.    There was a result of Wente that said something like if $ f= \nabla a \cdot \nabla^\perp b$ (where $a$ and $b$ have certain regularity assumptions,  but not really enough to see the right hand side is better than $L^1$)  then $ u \in C(\Omega)$.   I believe there is also a result that says something like if $f$ in a certain Hardy space (I am not familiar with these spaces) then one also has $ u$ continuous.

> QUESTION. I recall someone mentioning  a version similar to the above.  They had   said if $ f(x) ={\rm div}(F(x))$ where  $ F \in W^{1,1}(\Omega, R^2)$  then $ u \in C(\Omega)$.  So my question is.  Is this correct or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, but you must use the fact that $W^{1,1}$ is embedded in the Lorentz space $L^{2,1}$, see Helein's book, *Harmonic maps, conservation laws and moving frames*, theorem 3.3.10, you will find all the material about Hardy, Lorentz spaces in chapter 3 and more  generally this book is just awsome!!

Then using the fact the gradient of the  Green function $G$ is in $L^{2,\infty}$ because like $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert}$. Then you have $u=\nabla G * F$ is continuous.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to use Lorentz spaces? That is surprising, if true.

Comment: Yes it is. If u=ln(ln(r)), then \nabla u \in L^2 but conclusion fails

Comment: @Paul.  Thank you very much for the answer.  I guess at some point i should learn these more advanced spaces.  I will look at the references you mentioned.   thanks